# What version of gcc should i install on ubuntu 19.4 and how?

Tags: networking, gcc, ns2

So i tried installing gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 19.4 but i keep getting errors. I figured it must be happening because Ubuntu 19.4 does not support gcc 4.8. The error says that the package might be obsolete.
What do i do? 
Please help!

Comment: Ubuntu should ship with `gcc` as it is required for sevearl packages.

Comment: The [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/build-essential) package should install whatever you need. You might require additional packages for particular requirements.

Comment: **ns2** requires a nonPIE gcc/g++, version 5.4 or earlier. Of course gcc/g++ - 4.8 can be installed to 19.04 . Either from the 18.04 repo.
Or use `gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb`  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing  Provides `{ gcc48, g++48 }`